# How to create new event in Google Calendar API with java in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, google-calendar-api

I followed the quickstart guide that Google provides on Calendar API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java but they dont explain how to create a new event. I found this snippet of code online

```
public void createEvent(Calendar cal){
    Event event = new Event();
    event.setSummary("Event name here");
    event.setLocation("event place here");

    Date startDate = new Date();
    Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
    DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
    DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));
    Event createdEvent = cal.events().insert("primary", event).execute();
    System.out.println("Created event id: " + createdEvent.getId());
}
```

But it didn't help me, i got an error in the Event createdEvent = cal.events() section as events() doesn't exist. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your link to the documentation there is a link to [Create Events.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events) I won't duplicate the entire page here, but the gist is that you need to Create an `Event` object (perhaps called `MyNewEvent`), populate it, and then call:

```
MyNewEvent = service.events().insert("Some Calendar Id", MyNewEvent).execute();
```

Comment: what is `service`?